# Merge Sort: Segmentation error Core Dumped

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stdvector

I read the theory of merge sort algorithm and based on that i wrote an implementation of merge sort in C++ using the STL Vector class.

I know that a copy paste from any one of the trillion articles on internet about merge sort can solve this, but I wanted to try this one on my own.

When I run the code i get segmentation fault core dumped error, which is caused by the recursive functions not terminating.
Can anybody help me find the error in the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
void merge(std::vector<int>& arr,int last,int begin,int mid);
void mergeSort(std::vector<int>& arr,int begin, int last){ 
    std::cout<<"In merge sort";
    int mid; 
    if(begin<last){
      mid = (begin+last)/2;
      mergeSort(arr,begin,mid);
      mergeSort(arr,mid,last);
      merge(arr,last,begin,mid);
    } 
    return;
}
void merge(std::vector<int>& arr ,int last,int begin,int mid){
    if(last==begin){
        std::cout<<"Returned form finger";
        return; 
    }
    int b=begin,c=mid;
    std::vector<int> temp;
    while(b<mid&&c<last){
        if(arr[b]<arr[c]){
            temp.push_back(arr[b]);
            b++;
        }
        else{
            temp.push_back(arr[c]);
            c++;
        }
    }
    while(b<mid){temp.push_back(arr[b]);}
    while(c<last){temp.push_back(arr[c]);}
    arr.swap(temp);
    return;
}


int main(){
    std::vector<int> arr({2,4,1,5,3,6,2,4,3});   
    for(auto it=arr.begin();it!=arr.end();++it){
        std::cout<<*it<<' '; 
    }
    std::cout<<'\n';
   mergeSort(arr,0,8);
    for(auto it=arr.begin();it!=arr.end();++it){
        std::cout<<*it<<' '; 
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

I use gcc version 9.3.0 to compile the code using the terminal command

```
$ gcc filename.cpp -lstdc++
```

After analyzing the code i think the problem is in the merge function but i cant point out where it is. It would be helpful if anybody could help me and if possible suggest a few ways to optimize my code.

Comment: [How to implement classic sorting algorithms in modern C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c)

Comment: sorry, but I have to say it "...but I wanted to try this one on my own." and thats why you ask others to find the problem in your code. Allright :P. Did you already use a debugger?

Comment: Why do you compile with `gcc` instead of `g++`?

Comment: a debugger is a tool that lets you step through your code line by line to see where the problem is. If you don't know how to use it, now is the time

Comment: Your interval division is wrong. If `begin` is 0 and `end` is 1, you get `mid` as 0 and recurse on `mergeSort(0,1)`.

Comment: Side note: one reason that we specify ranges as half-open intervals is that it makes interval division much easier.

Comment: @idclev463035818 What i meant is that i wanted to do something without looking at the original code itself, and get my head around the idea of recursions. I wanted to form my own code for it. no i didn't use a debugger (i use vim to write code)

Comment: yes that fine, and my comment was not meant as an offense, but rather suggesting to take the "on my own" one step further by using a debugger. Writing the code is only a tiny part of programming, debugging takes at least as much time and is an important skill

Comment: There is one more problem. `arr` has 9 elements. You split it into two arrays `arr1` with 4 elements and `arr2` with 5 elements (or vice versa). Then you split `arr1` again into two arrays `arr11` with 2 elements and `arr12` with 2 elements. Then you merge these two arrays. You fill `temp` with these 4 elements and then you swap `arr.swap(temp);`. After this swap your array has 4 elements and every access is out of bounds. That's undefined behavior. Use `std::vector::at` instead of `std::vector::operator[]` for debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your recursion is wrong. In `main` you have a vector of nine elements.

```
std::vector<int> arr({2,4,1,5,3,6,2,4,3});
```

and you call `mergeSort` like this

```
mergeSort(arr,0,8);
```

So the third parameter to `mergeSort` is the last valid index of the vector you are sorting (it would have been better to use `arr.size() - 1`). Put another way mergeSort is sorting the *inclusive* range (0, 8).

Now in `merge_sort` you have this

```
void mergeSort(std::vector<int>& arr,int begin, int last) { 
    ...
    mergeSort(arr,begin,mid);
    mergeSort(arr,mid,last);
    ...
}
```

Recall merge sort is sorting the inclusive range (begin, last). So your recursion is going to sort the two inclusive ranges (begin,mid) and (mid,last). In other words `mid` is being included twice.

Since (very admirably) you want to program this for yourself, I'll leave you to figure out the fix.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answer(s) you have a serious problem in your `merge` function. The code you use to copy remaining elements to `temp` looks like:

```
while (b < mid) { temp.push_back(arr[b]); }
while (c < last) { temp.push_back(arr[c]); }
```

Notice that you never increment the `b` or `c` indices. That's an infinite loop that will eventually run out of memory calling `push_back`. The simple fix is something like:

```
while (b < mid) { temp.push_back(arr[b++]); }
while (c < last) { temp.push_back(arr[c++]); }
```